# Marble backsplash sealing

Tags: backsplash, marble

My marble backsplash was just completed and grouted yesterday afternoon.  I now realize it probably should have been sealed prior to installation but it wasn’t.  How long should I now wait before sealing it? Do I need to wait for it to be cured? How long would that be? My contractor said totally dry in 6 hours but I worry there is a difference between dry and dry enough to seal?

TIA
[image]![enter image description here]

Comment: Are you asking about sealing the grout? Or sealing the marble itself? I'm guessing you mean the marble, since you mention sealing before installation. But you may want to consider sealing the grout as well. In either case, it would help if the question were more clear.

Comment: You can contact the store/mfg for their recommended sealer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that marble should be sealed before installation because it can absorb color from the grout. Luckily, your marble and the grout are very similar in color. You need to seal the grout, and now the tile, after the grout has cured. The time for the grout to cure should be on the bag of grout, usually 24 to 48 hours. Pick a sealer for marble and follow directions, there are many to choose from.

I'm curious, didn't the contractor know to seal the marble first?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was under the impression that when I applied the sealer to the entire backsplash  that the same product would also be sealing the grout at the same time?  It sounds like I may need two diff products? Can you clarify that please.  Thank you! 

Re: didn’t the installer know.  I don’t know and it’s done so I figure there’s no point in taking it up with him now.  Moving forward and trying to not stress as I am happy with the finished project otherwise.

Comment: I can’t find a way to post a photo as a comment but I bought “511 Impregnator Sealer” for natural stone, tile, slate, ceramic tile, quartz and grout surfaces”

Comment: @Rachel  You can use the same product, 511 Sealer, for both marble and grout and can seal them at the same time once the grout has cured. WOO HOO.  Just follow the directions on the container.  It does really look nice.